# Unable to load dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr, package

I recently upgraded to R 3.5.0 (Windows 10).  Following this I have been unable to install dplyr.  The error message I get is:

```
Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
    cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
    1: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
       downloaded length 17723392 != reported length 17880019
    2: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) :
       error 1 in extracting from zip file 
    3: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")):
       cannot open compressed file 'BH/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

I have been able to install other packages and changing the mirror has not helped.  I have seen others report this error on but not a consistent fix.

Comment: You could to install the dependencies one by one to see where things break.

Comment: Something is cause it to hangup when downloading; like R stops the download when it takes a while.  I went to your github site and downloaded the zip file and trying to load it from local machine.

Comment: Careful though -- from GitHub you get the _sources_.  You want a binary if possible, from CRAN.  I'd try downloading the CRAN package differently: web browser, `wget` / `curl` / ...

Comment: Downloaded the package from CRAN to desktop and loaded it from there. That was the workaround

Comment: Thumbs up. We have seen that before; it is a combination of windows networking, and filesystem, and whatnot, conspiring against you.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
install.packages('tidyverse')
```

then

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Tidyverse is a package that includes dplyr and it usally has less problem to get installed.
It also contains ggplot2 so you might not need to load it anymore once you call tydyverse

Comment: Not helpful. OP reports that a component fails, you suggest the superset. Does not help with his issue, does it?

Comment: Even with that approach it still requires the dependencies.  The problem appears to be with loading BH and I get a similar error.  I remember seeing this discussed in other forums but I cannot find the fix at this point.

Comment: I happen to be the BH maintainer, and I know it is a humungous download.  Any chance it could have gotten corrupted by a firewall or filter?  Can you download it differently and then have `install.packages()` point to the local file?

Comment: Maybe with `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")`.

Comment: I need Rtools to build the program and get error message when loading it for R 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting dependencies = TRUE, like
install.packages("foo", dependencies=TRUE)

On several occasions this has helped me install packages, that wouldn't get installed otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately that has not helped.  It has something to do with BH.  It downloads to 99% (regardless of mirror) and then crashes. I don't have this problem with other zip files so I doubt it is my antiviral software.